# Verbs with multiple correct Present Perfect conjugations

Tags: verbs, present-perfect

From my time of learning conjugation tables by heart, I seem to remember that there were a few verbs which had multiple, grammatically correct,  ways of conjugating them into present perfect . However, googling a while did not reveal any, and I am starting to wonder whether my memory is simply betraying me. Any ideas?

Comment: You should probably search for "English verbs regular and irregular".  Some, like "hang", have two forms of the Past Participle. PP of "hang" is "hung" or "hanged".

Comment: It would be best to include the specific search queries you used, so we know what didn't work.

Comment: @VictorBazarov yes, so hang is actually already what I was looking for, Thanks! A semi-followup, does the correct conjugation depend on the context it is used in? At least to my ear, it sounds ok to say "I have hung my head in shame ever since what had happened at the party last week", and "He has hanged himself in a prison cell."

Comment: @sfeuz : for "hang", yes.  Others, I am not sure.  For instance, verb "light" has PP "lit" or "lighted", which I've seen used seemingly without regard to context.

Comment: Dreamed and dreamt perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by some of the commenters (like @VictorBarzov & @S.Baggy) there are several:

- hung vs hanged  <== special connotation
- dreamt vs dreamed
- got vs gotten
- drug vs dragged <== dialectic, use with caution
- lit vs lighted

Do be careful with *hanged*, as it has special connotation with a method of execution ([hanging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanging)). Also, be careful with *drug*; popular consensus pegs it as a variant limited to a dialect of English, not the language as a whole. Worse still, the more common definition is pharmacological, so perhaps it's better to avoid this one in anything but the most informal of settings.

Comment: I have never run into a single person who used "drug" as a conjugation of "drag". "Drug" as a verb always referred to the pharmacological sense.

Comment: When I lived in the northern midwestern United States, I didn't hear it either. It wasn't until I moved to the Southwest that I started hearing it being spoken. I've been informed that it is dialectic, so I'll edit my answer to reflect that.